# Toshiba L745 Brightness Problem, Fn Keys doesn't works

Tags: brightness

Has someone solved the brightness problem in Toshiba Laptops? I have a Toshiba L745-s4210 laptop with an Intel HD 3000 graphic card, after install ubuntu all works out of the box except the keys to change the brightness, there are some similar questions but some have nvidia graphic card instead intel, suggestions?

Comment: Did you try this solution ? http://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script/149265#149265

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/196863/27968 This workaround worked for me and a friend of mine.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug. You can view it here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/543294
Well someone posted a workaroudn like this:

```
1. Open a terminal (Program - Accessories - Terminal)
2. Type in "sudo gedit /etc/default/grub" (without the "")
3. Find the line that says: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash"
4. Edit it so it says: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
5. Save and exit
6. Run the command "sudo update-grub" (again without quotes of course)
7. Reboot and enjoy!
```

and yeah, it worked for me