# Can't adjust the brightness on a Toshiba C665 laptop

Tags: 12.04, brightness, toshiba

I had installed Ubuntu 12.04 i my Toshiba Laptop Satellite C665-I5011

In this I am not able to change the LCD brightness. When i press Fn+F6 or Fn+F7 the brightness bar is changing but the LCD screen brightness is not changing.

Can someone help me in this to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/130819/toshiba-l745-brightness-problem-fn-keys-doesnt-works?rq=1

Comment: are the other `fn` keys working?

Comment: yes..other function are working.. i tried volume Fn+3 and Fn+4

Comment: Is your problem same as the one linked above?

Comment: Have you tried from Sistem Settings?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Then type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`. It will ask for your password. Type it in.
3. Around the 11th line, there will be something like: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`. Change it to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`
4. Save the file by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. Then run `sudo update-grub` in the terminal.
5. Reboot and see if backlight adjustment works. If not, undo the changes you did above, by invoking the text editor as in steps 1 and 2.

Hope it helps.

Comment: this i had tried..it did not work for me

Answer (score 1):

Launch synaptic packet manager.
Type in ACPI, check acpi 1.61 and acpitool 0.5.1-3,mark for installation,click apply and then reboot or restart.

Should work.

Worked for me on Toshiba satellite L450D-11V.

Answer (score 1):

Did it work? Have the same problem. Couldn't fix it and wrote a skript in gedit:

```
#!/bin/sh

SYSFILE=/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
MAX=`cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness`
CUR=`cat $SYSFILE`

RET=`zenity --scale --value=$CUR --max-value=$MAX`

echo $RET | sudo tee $SYSFILE
```

started it in the terminal. Its not the best solution, but works.

Answer (score 0):

try this package and see if it's working after a reboot:

```
sudo apt-get install fnfxd fnfx-client
```

if you need acpi, you can find them here:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man4/acpi_toshiba.4.html

Comment: update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic
Reloading the module
ERROR: Module toshiba_acpi does not exist in /proc/modules
FATAL: Error inserting toshiba_acpi (/lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/toshiba_acpi.ko): No such device
dpkg: error processing toshiba-acpi-fix (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up fnfx-client:i386 (0.3-14ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 toshiba-acpi-fix
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
i get the above error

Comment: did the solution in the "possible duplicate" worked? if that solves the problem it would be easier than installing the acpi through the link in my answer (which is what your error is about)

Comment: it did not work :(

Comment: is there anything in the kernel i need to enable and re-compile ??