# Unable configure brightness or colors (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, colors

I've make a fresh install with Ubuntu 12.04. Unfortunatly i've a problem with colors and brightness settings. Before reinstall of Ubuntu, i used Ubuntu 10.10 with same graphic card, and same nvidia drivers.
Note: Only nvidia proprietary drivers works for my GeForce 8600 GTS.

Exemple:

- With nvidia-settings: adjust colors, brightness: no effects
- With *xgamma -gamma 0.5* : no effects
- Try to use f.lux or redshift: no effects

I try solutions found on internet like [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190935/cant-adjust-the-brightness-on-a-toshiba-c665-laptop#answer-191924) but no working to.

Any idea ?

Comment: Did you try this solution ? http://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script/149265#149265

Comment: Yes, but d'ont work :/

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+T and type

```
sudo aptitude install screentest -y
```

Type screentest and adjust your screen - with your monitor OSD

Check if when playing video you see people´s skin blue.
If you see the normal colors you are not using NVidia drivers.
You need to use them so you can use all the features.

Remember that your screen has probably light and color adjustments.
Always let the graphic card at default and set your screen first.

If you still need some adjustments you can do it.
Your screen might be overriding the results.
If you still have problems please post a screen shot of your graphic card settings panel so i can see it. I will be glad to help you.

Comment: Hi, thank's to reply. Yes i've nvidia drivers. i've already configure my screens withs theirs buttons. But i want to configure colors with my linux to ... (typically for use software like f.lux or redshift, i work on my computer and i need to adjust colors in night)