# Cannot adjust brightness after sleep

Tags: kernel, brightness, toshiba

I have a Toshiba Satellite R830 laptop with Ubuntu 12.04.1 64 bit. The <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> buttons adjust brightness until I put my laptop on sleep.

On wakeup they don't work any longer. Is there a solution or a workaround to this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a better solution than the one selected above.

1. Press Alt + F2 and type `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`.
2. Find the line than starts with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` and modify it as follows: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"`.
3. In a terminal (ctrl + alt + T) type `sudo update-grub`.
4. Reboot.

Problem solved.

More info here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight

### Edit

This solution no longer works on 13.10 and 14.04.

A solution that does is creating an xorg configuration file:

1. In a terminal type `sudo touch /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` to create the file.
2. Followed by `sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` to edit its content.
3. Then add the following content and save:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"

EndSection
```

Log out and in again.

Source: [Fix Brightness Control Not Working for Ubuntu 13.10 & 14.04](http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/)

Comment: You're adding a kernel parameter. Could you post a link, or directly describe why this is needed?

Comment: See modified answer. Not that I understand the details of it.

Comment: The second solution worked for me on Toshiba R830-13D running Fedora 21 Workstation with kernel 3.17.8.

Comment: Solution Ubuntu 14.04 also work for Lenovo T400! Thanks!

Comment: The first solution worked on an Asus Zenbook with Debian Jessie (kernel 3.16.0), however, I had to remove the backlight part because with that I couldn't change my backlight.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with a Toshiba Portege R935 in 12.04, and I discovered this (not so elegant) workaround:

- as root (not with `sudo` but actually changing user: `su root`), change the value in
  `sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

  for instance:

  ```
  echo 2937 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
  ```

**Warning**: these values are not between `0` and `7` (as the ones in the other directory), but between `284` and `4539`, or something like that.

Comment: Do you have to do it every time you need to change the brightness?

Comment: Well, yes, but I guess you can create a shortcut as the proposed solutions in other posts. I haven't do it yet, I'll let you know if I try. At least it's good to know where the problem is...