# Can't adjust brightness on a Sony Vaio T13 ultrabook

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, brightness, vaio, ultrabook

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7 in a Vaio T13 ultrabook.

I cannot use the the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to change the brightness. The bubble appears indicating that brightness is being changed but with no visual impact on the screen.

I've tried many solutions involving the manipulation of the /etc/default/grub file but none of them worked. Whenever I tried this manipulation the screen still didn't change, however the bubble stopped functioning properly.

This is not a problem of the <kbd>Fn</kbd> shortcut. Even when I try to change it in the Brightness and Lock on System Settings, the bar does scroll but the screen remains unchanged.

Does any one has a way around this mystery?

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/196863/27968) worked for me.

Open a terminal

Type `sudo su root` and press Enter

Type `echo 400 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`. Use the brightness level you wish.

Type `exit`

Close terminal

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem but it helps for the time being ... 

I still need to do this everytime I boot ...

Comment: I agree with you that it's not the ideal solution but at least it permits me to reduce battery consumption. If you want you can write a bash script with these commands and set it to run after boot.

Comment: echo 400 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness > /dev/null                    and you don't have to mess with su nonsense, it can also be used in scripts.

Answer (score 1):

**LCD Brightness Control**

This is fixable by editing one's xorg.conf file. Open a terminal window and type the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

This will open your X server configuration (after prompting for your password). You should see a section titled "Device" that looks as follows:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Default Device"
        Driver  "nvidia"
        Option  "NoLogo"        "True"
EndSection
```

Append a line so it appears like this:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Default Device"
        Driver  "nvidia"
        Option  "NoLogo"        "True"
        Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

You will need to restart your graphical server (or reboot) for this change to take effect.

Comment: On Ubuntu 13.04, `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at this thread:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2033273&page=2 (message 11, 12 and following).

Adding the scripts described in the above thread:

```
/etc/acpi/brightdown.sh

/etc/acpi/brightup.sh

/etc/acpi/events/sony-brightness-up

/etc/acpi/events/sony-brightness-do`wn
```

solves the problem and enables  the Fn+F4 or Fn+F5 keys.

Answer (score 0):

Install xbacklight (`sudo apt-get install xbacklight`) and try this command to reduce the brightness by 20%: `xbacklight -20`. If it works, then try this script (remember that you have to install inotify-tools and configure some of the paths inside the script -- there are comments inside for help):

[How to use xbacklight with brightness keys in a VAIO](https://askubuntu.com/questions/273045/how-to-use-xbacklight-with-brightness-keys-in-a-vaio)

It worked on my VPC.

Answer (score 0):

More than 2 years back i had similar problem with my **dell inspiron laptop**.At that time

[This work by kamal mostafa solved my problem and this patch has been already applied to 3.1 kernels](https://launchpad.net/~kamalmostafa/+archive/linux-kamal-mjgbacklight)

Now i have upgraded to **sony vaio ultrabook** and i have similar problem.After some research and hacking i am able to **solve brightness control to normal**.

1. First i found acer_wmi and sony_laptop kernel modules are loading while startup using 
   **lsmod** command.
2. Second i found was two backlight on /sys/class/backlight acpi_video and intel_backlight . 
   *here brightness keys working smoothly with /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video/brightness but changes are not reflected on screen*
   *second screen brightness changes do get reflected with intel_backlight *
   echo 400 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
3. acer_wmi and sony_laptop both modules checks if acpi_video is compatible and loads the module.
   *here i blacklisted acer_wmi and added kernel boot parameter to disable acpi_video and sony backlight which gets loaded by sony_laptop module while it detects acpi_video is incompatible*

   **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor sony_laptop.backlight=0"**

Now there will be only one intel_backlight in /sys/class/backlight folder which easily gets bind with gnome-powe-manager functioning brightness control keys.i am sure at this point it will also work kde's power-management tool

During boot you will find message but **it works fine**:

[    9.999247] sony_laptop: `0' invalid for parameter`backlight'

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2086359&p=12367720#post12367720) worked on my Sony Vaio T13:

1. open your terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)and type
   `sudo acpi_listen`.

Now this terminal will "listen" to the keyboard.

2. Hit the shortcut for brightness down and brightness up, in this case:
   <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.
   You should see how this is interpreted on terminal. Typically something like:

> sony/hotkey SNC 00000001 00000011
>   sony/hotkey SNC 00000001 00000010

or similar.

3. Open another terminal without closing the previous one. And type:
   `gksu gedit /etc/acpi/events/sony-brightness-up`

this will open a text file. Copy and paste in the text file this code:

> event=sony/hotkey SNC 00000001 00000011
>   action=/etc/acpi/brightup.sh

make sure your doing it right (that's why you should have kept the first terminal open): if the output from step 2 was different then you'd have to type

> event="whatever-was-in-your-output"
>   action=/etc/acpi/brightup.sh

save and close the text file.

4. In terminal type: `gksu gedit /etc/acpi/events/sony-brightness-down`
   this opens a different text file. In the text file copy-paste this (again, change the bit "event= ..." if necessary):

> event=sony/hotkey SNC 00000001 00000010
>   action=/etc/acpi/brightdown.sh

save and close.

5. In terminal type `gksu gedit  /etc/acpi/brightdown.sh`
   and in the text file that will open type:

> #!/bin/bash
>   curr=`cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness`
>   if [ $curr -gt 406 ]; then
>      curr=$((curr-406));
>      echo $curr  > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness;
>   fi

save and close.

6. In terminal type:`gksu gedit  /etc/acpi/brightup.sh`
   and in the document type:

> #!/bin/bash
>   curr=`cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness`
>   if [ $curr -lt 4477 ]; then
>      curr=$((curr+406));
>      echo $curr  > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness;
>   fi

save and close.

To make these scripts executable, type in terminal:
 `sudo chmod +x /etc/acpi/events/sony-brightness-up

sudo chmod +x /etc/acpi/events/sony-brightness-down

sudo chmod +x /etc/acpi/brightdown.sh

sudo chmod +x /etc/acpi/brightup.sh`

7. Finally, restart acpid by typing in terminal:
   `sudo service acpid restart`