# Brightness doesn't work after sleep with Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: suspend, brightness, toshiba-satellite

I have a problem with my Toshiba Satellite R850.

The brightness-adjustment via the Function-Keys and the system settings works properly, but not after putting the Laptop on Sleep-Mode.

The answer given in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196801/cannot-adjust-brightness-after-sleep) did the trick for me with Ubuntu 12.10 64-Bit,
but doesn't seem to work with Ubuntu 13.04 64-Bit.

Has anyone experienced the same and know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using an earlier trick to control brightness but it is not very practical.

```
echo 300 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Change the 300 to whatever you want.

Waiting for a better solution.

Comment: Thanks, this works even after the sleep mode , but like you said, it is not very practical. I rather reboot to solve the issue, but this ain't a permanent solution...