# How to control brightness on toshiba laptop?

Tags: brightness

I have toshiba satellite L745 with nvidia GEFORCE graphics card. I installed nvidia server setting from ubuntu software center. Still I can't decrease the brightness. When I use the function key to decrease, brightness indicator shows it's decreasing but it doesn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot change backlight brightness Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/476664/cannot-change-backlight-brightness-ubuntu-14-04) and [Screen brightness isn't taking effect on a Lenovo Z570](http://askubuntu.com/questions/468277/screen-brightness-isnt-taking-effect-on-a-lenovo-z570)

Answer (score 1):

Looking up on this very site has brought me to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130819/toshiba-l745-brightness-problem-fn-keys-doesnt-works) question and the solution mentioned there was:

> 1. Open a terminal (Program - Accessories - Terminal)
> 2. Type in "sudo gedit /etc/default/grub" (without the "")
> 3. Find the line that says: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash"
> 4. Edit it so it says: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
> 5. Save and exit
> 6. Run the command "sudo update-grub" (again without quotes of course)
> 7. Reboot and enjoy!

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Please don't copy other peoples answers from the site as yours, leave a comment below the question saying it is a duplicate -1

Comment: I would definitely keep it in mind. Understood :)

Comment: OK I will change my vote so you don't loose rep, just remember, we have a way to deal with duplicate questions.

Comment: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash"    , is not in the file. Rather you'd find GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"